# Converting a large sequence to a sequence with no repeats in scala really fast

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing

So I have this large sequence, with a lot of repeats as well, and I need to convert it into a sequence with no repeats. What I have been doing so far has been converting the sequence to a set, and then back to the original sequence. Conversion to the set gets rid of the duplicates, and then I convert back into the set. However, this is very slow, as I'm given to understand that when converting to set, every pair of elements is compared, and the makes the complexity O(n^2), which is not acceptable. And since I have access to a computer with thousands of cores (through my university), I was wondering whether making things parallel would help.

Initially I thought I'd use scala Futures to parallelize the code in the following manner. Group the elements of the sequence into smaller subgroups by their hash code. That way, I have a subcollection of the original sequence, such that no element appears in two different subcollections and and every element is covered. Now I convert these smaller subcollections to sets, and back to sequences and concatenate them. This way I'm guaranteed to get a sequence with no repeats.

But I was wondering if applying the toSet method on a parallel sequence already does this. I thought I'd test this out in the scala interpreter, but I got roughly the same time for the conversion to parallel set vs the conversion to the non parallel set.
I was hoping someone could tell me whether conversion to parallel sets works this way or not. I'd be much obliged. Thanks.

EDIT: Is performing a toSet on a parallel collection faster than performing toSet on a non parallel collection?

Comment: "I'm given to understand that when converting to set, every pair of elements is compared" Who told you that?

Comment: The person I'm working with said that, but I'm not too sure. But does toSet work in linear time, or quadratic time?

Comment: Probablistically, amorphized linear time, which for all intents and purposes means linear.
I think you should probably read about hashtables before you start parallel programming in scala :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, my primary question wasn't clear enough, and I've put that in the edit.

Comment: What is in your sequence?

Answer (score 3):

`.distinct` with some of the Scala collection types is `O(n)` (as of Scala 2.11). It uses a hash map to record what has already been seen. With this, it linearly builds up a list:

```
  def distinct: Repr = {
    val b = newBuilder
    val seen = mutable.HashSet[A]()
    for (x <- this) {
      if (!seen(x)) {
        b += x
        seen += x
      }
    }
    b.result()
```

(`newBuilder` is like a mutable list.)

Answer (score -1):

Just thinking outside the box, would it be possible that you prevent the creation of these doublons instead of trying to get rid of them afterwards ?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It should probably be a comment